# Deploy a C# application with Oracle 10g Database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deployment, oracle10g

I am developing a C# app for my graduation project and I need to know how to Deploy a C# application with Oracle 10g Database.

Comment: Do you mean how to connect to the DB, or query it? Or are you actually trying to deploy an application from the DB itself somehow?

Comment: i need to know how to create a setup with the DB